# Impossible to modify value in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a Football related app where users have many clubs. In this context, when a User is interacting with one of his clubs, I want a variable in User "current_club_id" to refer to said Club.

So when the User clicks on the club's name, I want to set this current_club_id. Here is _clubs.html.erb, which is rendered in User/show

```
<tr>
  <td class="club">
    <span class="nom"><%= button_to club.nom, {:action => "assign_current_club", :controller => "users",  :id => current_user.id, :club_actif_id => club.id } %></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and here is the assign_current_club method in Users_controller

```
def assign_current_club
    @club = Club.find(params[:club_actif_id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.current_club_id = @club.id
    @user.save
    redirect_to @club
  end
```

For some reason, the "current_club_id" cannot be modified/updated.
Please help!

Comment: if `@user` cannot be saved, `@user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence` should have the error. Else try using @user.save! and the error will be shown in your logs

Comment: I get the following error:
Password can't be blank and Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
Do you know what can be the cause? I'm signed in as the User... Maybe it's due to fact that I have a attr_accessor :password in my model? I've done this by following the rails tutorial which was for Rails 3. I'm using Rails 4

Comment: This error was occuring because of the validation validates :password, :presence     => true. I solved it by adding :if => :password to this validation. Thank you for your help, your are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   get :assign_current_club, on: :member, as: :assign_current_club #-> url.com/users/:id/assign_current_club
end

<%= button_to club.nom, assign_current_club_path(current_user.id), params: {club_actif_id: club.id} %>

def assign_current_club
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    redirect_to clubs_path(params[:club_actif_id]) if @user.update(current_club_id: params[:club_actif_id])
end
```

---

You need to make sure you have `club_actif_id` in your `User` model.

If it exists in the `User` model, you should be able to pass the above code to get it to change. You **don't** need `attr_accessible` in Rails any more (only required for Rails 3).

Comment: OP problem isn't caused by `current_club_id` not existing in the model as that would raise a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Doing this gets me the following error message :
undefined method `assign_current_club_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe5dbc57e98>:0x007fe5db655c70>

Comment: I found the reason, the user was not saving because the password was not entered (conflict with validates password presence). I resolved it by adding :if => :password to my validation. Thanks for your help!